# Q: Nexus OSS 3.2.1 Upgrade plan

Tags: open-source, upgrade, nexus

We have to upgrade our Nexus OSS ver 2.14.2 which is currently running on Windows to the latest Nexus OSS version 3.2.1 but on Linux machine.
What our plan to upgrade is

First 2.14.2 to 2.14.3
Then 2.14.3 to 3.2.1
After that Migration.

Does it sound a proper plan or we should re-consider it? Is there any potential risk? Suggestions are welcome.

Please share your experiences while Upgrading and Migration.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan is good, upgrade to 2.14.3 first, then go to 3.2.1.  Both upgrades are very safe.  And in fact, in the case of the 3.2.1 upgrade your existing 2.14.3 will be left intact. The upgrade from 2 to 3 imports the configuration and data from Nexus 2 while leaving the original instance untouched.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion.
How it is in terms of performance if Nexus is running on Linux instead of Windows??